# What is going on in 2 Samuel 1, when David ordered the death of the Amalekite who kill Saul at Saul's request?

Tags: david, 2-samuel, saul

Saul said to the Amalekite in

> 2 Samuel 1:9 'Stand here by me and kill me! I'm in the throes of death, but I'm still alive.'